# 14 hour transit time at Sydney airport with no visa arrangements

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, transit, sydney, syd

On return flight from Bali-Sydney-Samoa, the transit is 14 hours as there is only one flight 4 days a week from Sydney-Samoa. I arrive at 6.00am and depart that evening, so technically not staying overnight which I know is not allowed in Sydney airport.

Flying Samoa-Sydney-Bali was fine with only 1.5 hour transit, but am worried about return. Applied for transit visa but has not been processed yet, did not know that a minor conviction for disorderly behaviour in NZ years ago (with no jail time, just a $200 fine) would hold up processing of transit visa. So, have not received transit visa yet and unlikely to receive before return flight on 3 October 2012.

Has anyone experienced a longer than 8 hour transit (during day time) -- will Airlines let me board in Bali to return, or will I be denied flight in Bali??
Thanks for any help

Comment: Who are you flying with? What passport are you on?

Comment: NZer, it would appear. Their flight is in a couple of hours, hopefully it goes well...

Comment: Currently too vague - what passport, what conviction, as well as being very specific and niche. Rewording as something like 'What is Bali's rules for transit visas with convictions' or similar would make it less niche, and if edited as such we could revisit it. Closing for now.